# ElectronJS + WebPack + JS файл в Base64

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

Разрабатываю проект на ElectronJS.
Пока новичок в WebPack.
WebPack упаковывает все в один файл.
Но есть несколько файлов - js-скриптов, которые просто хранятся в JS-файлах (JS-библиотеки для браузера)
И сейчас они подключаются кодом:

```
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(`./script.js`, 'utf8')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы WebPack закодировал этот файл в Base64-строку, и поместил эту строку в общий бандл?

А... и чуть не забыл: Файл index.html тоже хорошо бы упаковать в бандл